# Storing an object to database and then retrieving it back again

Tags: php, oop, object

Please excuse the long post - I've tried to be as succinct as possible, whilst giving as much detail as I can ... and I've historically been a procedural PHP programmer, now getting my feet wet with objects.

I'm working on a test project where I'm using a 3rd party class (loaded via phar) to capture a stream from an online server. The online server posts events, I capture (using "capture.php") each event with the 3rd party class, serialize the data and then store it to a MySQL database as a BLOB field.

```
//capture.php
// include phar file
require_once 'PAMI-1.72.phar';
// set include path to have pami's phar first
ini_set('include_path', implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array('phar://pami.phar', ini_get('include_path'))));

use PAMI\Client\Impl\ClientImpl as PamiClient;
use PAMI\Message\Event\EventMessage;
use PAMI\Listener\IEventListener;
$pamiClient = new PamiClient($pamiClientOptions);

// Open the connection
$pamiClient->open();

$pamiClient->registerEventListener(function (EventMessage $event) {
// Following line dumps the event to a text file in rawCapture.php
//var_dump($event);
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
exit;
}

$serializedData = $mysqli->real_escape_string(serialize($event));

$sql = 'insert into obj (data) values ("' . $serializedData . '")';
echo "\r\nSQL is $sql\r\n";    
});
```

In a different script ("read.php" - I know - I'm VERY creative in script naming) I ensure that I have the include files to the class definition files, pick up the first entry in the database, pull the BLOB data and then unserialize it. At this point I'm testing the variable type in read.php and the variable is an object:

```
require_once 'PAMI-1.72.phar';
// set include path to have pami's phar first
ini_set('include_path', implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array('phar://pami.phar', ini_get('include_path'))));

use PAMI\Client\Impl\ClientImpl as PamiClient;
use PAMI\Message\Event\EventMessage;
use PAMI\Listener\IEventListener;

/* All the MySQL stuff to get the $data from the db */

$event = unserialize($data);

echo "\r\nevent is " . gettype($event) . "\r\n";
print_r($event);
```

And this is the result I get:

```
event is object
PAMI\Message\Event\NewchannelEvent Object
(
[rawContent:protected] => Event: Newchannel
Privilege: call,all
Channel: Local/s@tc-maint-00006a43;2
ChannelState: 4
ChannelStateDesc: Ring
CallerIDNum: 
CallerIDName: 
AccountCode: 
Exten: s
Context: tc-maint
Uniqueid: 1443368640.57856
[lines:protected] => Array
(
)

[variables:protected] => Array
(
)

[keys:protected] => Array
(
[event] => Newchannel
[privilege] => call,all
[channel] => Local/s@tc-maint-00006a43;2
[channelstate] => 4
[channelstatedesc] => Ring
[calleridnum] => 
[calleridname] => 
[accountcode] => 
[exten] => s
[context] => tc-maint
[uniqueid] => 1443368640.57856
)

[createdDate:protected] => 1443368636
)
```

Ok - so far so good, IMHO. This certainly appears to be an object, all the data certainly appears to have been stored correctly (rawCapture.php is another script which also polls the data and var_dumps the **same** events out to a text file, so that I can "compare" and ensure that everything is being recorded correctly).

However, now I want to deal with some of the object data and this is where I'm having issues. For example, I'm trying to obtain the value of the Uniqueid, but using `$id = $event->Uniqueid;` I get the following error `PHP Notice:  Undefined property: PAMI\Message\Event\NewchannelEvent::$Uniqueid in /home/dave/objRead.php on line 69`

Now I'm stuck.  I've tried checking that $event is in fact an object, using get_object_vars():

```
$objVars = get_object_vars($event);
if(is_null($objVars)){
echo "\r\nobjVars doesn't appear to be an object?!\r\n";
} else {
if(is_array($objVars)){
print_r($objVars);
} else {
echo "\r\nobjVars isn't an array!!\r\n";
}
}
```

and I'm getting my own error code "objVars doesn't appear to be an object?!".

Can anyone give me some advice on what on earth I'm doing wrong??

Also  -  I've tried to keep indentation in the code sections above but it wouldn't let me post without removing them. I've also amended my OP to show that I'm including the 3rd party code so that the class definitions are loaded, and the line that I use to `unserialize` the data from the MySQL table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the case of `Uniqueid` in `$id = $event->Uniqueid;` to lower case? 
So it would be `$id = $event->uniqueid;`

Comment: `PHP Notice:  Undefined property: PAMI\Message\Event\NewchannelEvent::$uniqueid in /home/dave/objRead.php on line 54`

I had used the initial uppercase variable because I'm very aware of case sensitivity, and that's what had been listed when I used `print_r($event);`, but I took your suggestion and got pretty much the same response back, even trying calling the lowercase...

Comment: Apologies, nomistic, but I do believe I did answer Carlos' question. "... I took your suggestion and got ... the same response back"

Am I missing something here? I don't mean to offend...